# how to use imgVar inTHREE3.ImageUtils.loadTexture( imgVar )?

Tags: three.js

taken from AlteredQualia demo:

```
map = THREE3.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "textures/terrain/grasslight-big.jpg" );
map.wrapS = map.wrapT = THREE3.RepeatWrapping;
map.repeat.set( 16, 16 );

var planeGeo = new THREE3.PlaneGeometry( 200, 200 );

ground = new THREE3.Mesh( planeGeo, new THREE3.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff,    ambient: 0xffffff, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 50, map: map, perPixel: true, metal: true } ) );
```

I have extracted png data from an HTML canvas with ExtJS Ext.getDom('cnvs_img').src; into a var and the var string starts " data:image/png;base64, ..." so think it is valid. I want to use this data instead of loading from disk with loadTexture. Would appreciate some pointers, thanks.

THREE3.ImageUtils.loadTexture( imgVar ) does not work of course :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load a texture from a `dataURL`, you can follow this pattern:

```
var image = document.createElement( 'img' );

image.src = dataURL;

image.onload = function() {

    var texture = new THREE.Texture( image );
    texture.needsUpdate = true; // important!

    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { 
        color: 0xffffff, 
        map: texture
    } );

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );

};
```

three.js r.67